# DateTime fails to parse 24:00:00 in the HH:mm:ss format

Tags: c#, datetime

I noticed quite an interesting error when parsing some times.

`DateTime` fails to parse `24:00:00`. Under some Googling and Stacking, I found out that `DateTime` only recognizes `00 - 23` (what the?????), so if your input is `24:00:00`, you're out of luck. You would think someone would put in a condition to equate `24:00:00` as `00:00:00` (the midnight), but not yet..

My question is, how do I allow `DateTime` to allow me to parse `24:00:00`?

*Unfortunately I cannot to use `NodaTime` under specification reasons (sorry Jon. I love your library though).*

**Experimentation below:**

**An `input` of `2014-03-18 24:00:00` would present the following error. Expected.**

[image]

---

**An `input` of `2014-03-18 23:59:59` would successfully parse. Expected.**

[image]

---

**An `input` of 2014-03-19 00:00:00` would successfully parse. Expected.**

[image]

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no such thing as 2400 hours. It wraps to 0000 (at least in every reference I've seen).

Comment: In which 24H clock you saw 24:00:00? The time is invalid. Its another day then.

Comment: So you'd also expect 2014-03-18 48:00:00 to become 2014-09-20 00:00:00 ?

Comment: well, correct is 00:00:00 not 24:00:00

Comment: I understand this "technical" facet, but I would expect it to round it up to the next day. For example, `2014-03-18 24:00:00` would become `2014-03-19 00:00:00`.

Comment: @MichaelTodd Could there be any way to allow my parsing to wrap it to 00:00:00 (the next day)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing times above 24 hours in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208607/parsing-times-above-24-hours-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Ah interesting - @ThomasW. I'll look at that!

Comment: Most libraries with a few exceptions are not capable of parsing "24:00" (interpreting it as midnight at the end of current day equal to midnight on the next day) although this is an absolute valid string from ISO-8601-perspective.

Comment: Wanted to add that, for example, xs:DateTime in XML very well accepts a value of 24:00. So this seems to be valid. But .NET DateTime has a different definition. This can lead to problems if an XML is deserialized in .NET where the XSD finds the value to be valid, but the value cannot be deserialized into a DateTime.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no "24th hour" support in the DateTime class.

[The hour (HH/H, 24-hour clock) must be 0-23, inclusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). This is why 00:00:00 is valid, but 24:00:00 is not.

Change 24:00:00 to 00:00:00 (before parsing) and, if needed, advance the day as appropriate (after parsing).

---

The following will work on times in the provided format (but only up to the 24th hour) although it doesn't account for an arbitrary format. Supporting different format strings only adds additional complications.

```
DateTime ParseWithTwentyFourthHourToNextDay (string input) {
    var wrapped = Regex.Replace(input, @"24:(\d\d:\d\d)$", "00:$1");
    var res = DateTime.ParseExact(wrapped, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
    return wrapped != input
        ? res.AddDays(1)
        : res;
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out that there IS a `24:00` time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00 - but it's not supported by the `DateTime` class.

Answer (score 4):

24:00:00 doesn't exist.  It is 00:00:00 - 23:59:59

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to parse 24:00:00 as a valid time expression when it would be like saying  09:05:60. The roof for time is 23:59:59.99999999999 and after that, it turns over to 00:00:00.

Answer (score -1):

Before parsing, do a simple search and replace - replace '24:00:00' with '00:00:00' and then parse as usual.

Answer (score -1):

*Convert to Minute.*

```
if t.TotalMinutes < 0

double _24h = 0;
_24h = 1440 + t.TotalMinutes;
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_24h);
```